# Django image not showing up in template (not URLs issue)

Tags: django, django-templates

I've added the neccessary elements to the URLs.py.

The image is NOT stored in the database, it's just a background image.

The source of the img folder is 'storiesapp/static/storiesapp/img'

**Settings.py (i've been trying different things as shown)**

```
STATIC_URL = '/storiesapp/static/storiesapp/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "/storiesapp/static/storiesapp/img/",
    "/static/storiesapp/img/",
    "/storiesapp/img/",
    "/img/",
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS =[
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]




MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    # full path where all images are stored - os.path will create the directory regardless of the operating system
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    #
```

.**URLs.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

...

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

.

**I'm trying all of the following**

```
     <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="./assets/img/image.png">
     <img src="static/storiesapp/img/image.png">
     <img class='img-responsive' src="{{ MEDIA.URL }}{{ image.png }}" />
```

Comment: If its getting stored in database then you have to use database field url to access the image. Please update the question with MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT settings. Also relevant model and views.

Comment: No, as I stated it's not stored in the datbase. it's just an icon for the navigation bar, so it has nothing to do with the models or views. I've updated with the location of the media files/

Comment: check [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Unfortunately that's the issue, I've already read this and don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `"<img src="{% static 'storiesapp/img/image.png' %}"/>"`.

It was the wrong syntax.

I was able to come to this solution because I realized that my CSS templates, which I can see are working, are also using the static folder so it couldn't be a problem with the way anything is set up.